# How does change in Passing parameters changes the output of the Code?

Tags: c++

When I pass only Sum as Parameter in My coin Exchange Problem  to find no of ways to find the amount Sum..
Example
`if the coins are {2,3,5} and the desired sum is 9` i get correct output as `8`.
This code :

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int n, sum, a[105];

int fun(int sum) {
    int S = 0;
    if(sum == 0) return 1;
    
    if(sum < 0) return 0;
    
    for(int i=1;i<=n;i++) {
        
        S += fun(sum - a[i]);
    }
    
    
    return S;
}

int main()
{
    cin >> n;
    cin >> sum;
    for(int i=1;i<=n;i++ ) {
        cin >> a[i];
    }
    cout << fun(sum);
    

    return 0;
}
```

But when I also give Current Index as a parameter it gives me output as `3` which is wrong.

This code :

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int n, sum, a[105];

int fun(int sum, int idx) {
    int S = 0;
    if(sum == 0) return 1;
    if(idx > n) return 0;
    if(sum < 0) return 0;
    
    for(int i=idx;i<=n;i++) {
        
        S += fun(sum - a[i], i);
    }
    
    
    return S;
}

int main()
{
    cin >> n;
    cin >> sum;
    for(int i=1;i<=n;i++ ) {
        cin >> a[i];
    }
    cout << fun(sum,1);
    

    return 0;
}
```

But WHY??
Is my parameter passing in this case is wrong?

Comment: Maybe because you have global variable `sum` and you're trying to pass different variable `sum` in your `fun()` method.

Comment: @AP11 but my First code worked Fine

Comment: It actually throw `Segmentation fault`, because you have wrong for loop. Why do you even pass the sum as a parameter?

Comment: Atleast Upvote friends so it reaches many..

Comment: that's not how it works, my friend.

Comment: I mean, why do you make it so difficult? What is the purpose of your code?

Comment: @AP11 but i passed many TestCases I didnt found ```Segmentation fault```

Comment: Again, what is the purpose of the code? I want to help you, but I don't know, what are you trying to achieve? Just sum up the elements in array? Help me, so I can help you.

Comment: @AP11 the Ways to get the Desired Sum from given coins like i already mentioned ```if the coins are {2,3,5} and the desired sum is 9``` in how many ways i can get the Sum  ```9``` from those coins using them. We can use them multiple times

Comment: But you already pass the `sum`, so why bother computing it?

Comment: @AP11  u mean again writing it with parameter idx?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225879/discussion-between-dhondi-pranav-and-ap11).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have the same result between your 2 solutions because in the first, at each "function call", you will iterate from 1 to N and in your second solution, you will iterate from Index to N. So the number of loop will be different.

Comment: But when i Call the Function I pass idx as ```1``` So its technically the same

Comment: For the first call yes, but you're using the recursivity... So you'll call many times the same function... This is the principle of the recursivity

Comment: Could u give me the Example?

Comment: If you entered N = 10, here are the number of loops at each "call" :
```
- 1st : 1 to 10
- 2 : 2 to 10
- 3 : 3 to 10
and so on...
```

Rather than your first solution :
```
- 1st : 1 to 10
- 2nd : 1 to 10
- 3rd : 1 to 10
and so on...
```

Comment: But idx gets incremented each time so i dont think it will call the same funtion many times

Comment: In your first solution your for loop iterate all the time from 1 to N instead of Index to N in your latest... So at the end the number of calls will not be the same... Do you see that ?

Comment: Yea got u... The no. Of function call really chages in my 2nd method

Comment: Got the difference atlast thanks...;)